# Android SDK Tools Linux: Download from Preview/Beta Channels without Android Studio

Tags: android, linux, sdk

I've spent days on this and asking here really is my last resort.

On a headless Linux installation, I am trying to install the Android SDK tools off the beta/preview channel. Current version is 25.3.0 ([see here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017)).

I have a previous (stable!) version of the tools installed on the machine, so I can run "android" and other tools. The command-line version of the Android SDK Update shows me only the stable releases, no previews. So I can't use that. Looking at the official package XML [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-12.xml) tells nothing about the location of any preview-downloads.

I tried modifying all and every single Android SDK URL known to me, and none delivered a valid response. For instance, you could get the stable tools like so:

`wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip`

But modifying this to the following does not work:

`wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.3.0-linux.zip`

Any ideas how I can switch over to the preview channel, or just download the tools? All I am looking for is the new emulator.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that SDK tools 25.3.1 is now the current stable version. I can't download it either.

Comment: Windows tools are at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3773319.zip, Linux tools at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3773319.zip. Don't know where the Mac tools are.

Comment: @ErikBrowne how did you get the number?

Comment: Found it in a comment to a Google bug report.